# shard selection from a set, while elements are being added and removed

Tags: algorithm, sharding

I have a use case with `n` servers and `m` clients. Each client gets its own shard of `k` servers to use, where `k < n`. This technique is called [shuffle sharding](https://aws.amazon.com/builders-library/workload-isolation-using-shuffle-sharding/) and it's used for probabilistic isolation between the `m` client workloads.

In a naive implementation, you can choose a random set of `k` out of the `n` servers as the shard for each client, however that will lead to a fairly wide distribution of # of clients per server (causing hot-spotting / overload on some of the servers, and low utilization on others). Instead, if you know `k`, `n`, and `m` a priori you could create a set of `m` shards that are perfectly balanced across all servers -- each server will be within 1 of the mean number of clients per server, `k * m / n`.

I want a shard choosing algorithm that will do that, plus also satisfies the classic load balancing property that if `x` more servers are added to the pool / `x` servers are removed, on average the ratio of servers in each shard that change when you recompute your shards equals `x / n` (or some low constant multiple of that value).

Comment: Is m a set value or is it different for each client?

Comment: @petern0691 `m` is the number of clients, so it doesn't vary per client. you can treat it as a constant value though.

Comment: Sorry. I meant k. Does each client get the same allocation of servers?

Comment: @petern0691 yes, you can assume the shard size `k` is the same for all clients

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following do the job:

[EDIT 20221023] Rationalised high level algorithm below:

List n idle servers
Add client k processes
If new client will smother an existing client or an existing client will smother the new client
Spread the new client to avoid smothering if possible.
Else
Allocate first k servers in list to client
Sort list of servers in ascending order clients per server

(Smothering: Where a client's spread processes over servers covers all of another client's spread of processes. If a smothering client's servers are compromised then so are all of the smothered client's servers.)

Remove client k
Deallocate servers for the client
While difference between min and max clients per server > threshold
For server at max end of list of servers randomly select a client
Deallocate the k_max servers for the client
Add client k_max servers
Sort list of servers in ascending order of clients on server

(k_max is the servers for the client with number of clients = max)

Remove client servers
Remove client
Deallocate clients from removed servers
For each client deallocated
Add client k_deallocated processes
Sort list of servers in ascending order of clients per server

Insert x servers
Add x servers at start of list
While difference between min and max clients per server > threshold
For server at max end of list of servers randomly select a client
Deallocate the k_max servers for the client
Add client k_max servers
Sort list of servers in ascending order of clients per server

[EDIT 20221023]

There is a lot to this matter.

The code below is a partial implementation of the above. It:

- does not yet to do explicit load balancing
- favours desmothering over load balancing
- does not assume a constant k per client
- is only an exploratory test of concept / strawman

  ```js
  shardActions = [
  [ "+", "s", "", 23 ],
  [ "+", "c", "teal", 3 ],
  [ "+", "c", "blue", 10 ],
  [ "+", "c", "yellow", 5 ],
  [ "+", "c", "grey", 3 ],
  [ "+", "c", "orange", 7 ],
  [ "+", "c", "tan", 7 ],
  [ "+", "c", "red", 7 ],
  [ "+", "c", "wheat", 7 ],
  [ "-", "s", "grey", "" ],
  [ "+", "c", "lightgreen", 7 ],
  [ "+", "c", "lightgrey", 5 ],
  [ "+", "c", "cyan", 6 ],
  [ "+", "c", "grey", 4 ],
  [ "+", "c", "brown", 6 ],
  [ "+", "c", "tan", 2 ],
  [ "+", "c", "purple", 16 ],
  [ "+", "c", "beige", 6 ],
  [ "+", "c", "lightblue", 6 ],
  [ "+", "c", "blueviolet", 6 ],
  [ "+", "c", "coral", 6 ],
  [ "+", "c", "crimson", 6 ],
  [ "+", "c", "darkblue", 6 ],
  [ "+", "s", "", 5 ],
  [ "+", "c", "yellowgreen", 12 ],
  [ "+", "c", "darkolivegreen", 4 ],
  [ "+", "c", "darkred", 4 ],
  [ "+", "c", "plum", 10 ],
  [ "+", "c", "deeppink", 2 ],
  [ "+", "c", "aquamarine", 11 ],
  [ "+", "c", "deepskyblue", 2 ],
  [ "+", "c", "fuchsia", 9 ],
  [ "+", "c", "gold", 1 ],
  [ "+", "c", "indigo", 12 ],
  [ "+", "c", "khaki", 12 ],
  [ "+", "c", "lightcyan", 12 ],
  [ "-", "c", "purple", "" ],
  [ "-", "c", "blue", "" ],
  [ "-", "c", "gold", "" ],
  [ "+", "c", "pink", 12 ],
  [ "+", "c", "turquoise", 19 ],
  [ "+", "c", "blue", 10 ],
  [ "+", "c", "violet", 16 ],
  [ "+", "c", "powderblue", 4 ],
  [ "+", "c", "salmon", 5 ],
  [ "+", "c", "olive", 4 ],
  [ "+", "c", "springgreen", 5 ],
  [ "+", "c", "purple", 16 ],
  [ "+", "c", "chocolate", 7 ]
  ]

  var nextAction = 0;
  var nextServerId = 0
  var servers = [];
  var clientsName = [];
  var clientsProcesses = [];
  var clientsServers = [];

  function displayServers() {
      var display = '<tr><th>Server</th><th>Clients</th><th>Number</th><tr>';
      for ( var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++ ) {
          var clientDisp = '';
          for ( var j = 0; j < servers[i][1].length; j++ ) {
              clientDisp += '<span style="background: ' + servers[i][1][j] + '">' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '</span>';
          }
          display += '<tr><td>' + servers[i][0] + '</td><td>' + clientDisp + '</td><td>' + servers[i][1].length + '</td>' + '</tr>';
      }
      document.getElementById("servers").innerHTML = display;
  }

  const smotherLimit = 0;

  function smothering(alloc, incr, offset) {
      var clientsExposed = [];
      var clientsExposures = [];
      var clientNdx;
      var srvNdxes = [];
      for ( ndx = offset; ndx < alloc + offset; ndx++ ) {
          var srvNdx = ndx * incr % servers.length;
          if ( srvNdxes.includes(srvNdx) ) {
              break;
          } else {
              srvNdxes.push(srvNdx);
              for ( var i = 0; i < servers[srvNdx][1].length; i++ ) {
                  clientNdx = clientsExposed.indexOf(servers[srvNdx][1][i]);
                  if ( clientNdx == -1 ) {
                      clientsExposed.push(servers[srvNdx][1][i])
                      clientsExposures.push([clientsProcesses[clientsName.indexOf(servers[srvNdx][1][i])], 1]);
                  } else {
                      clientsExposures[clientNdx][1] += 1;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      if ( clientsExposed.length > 0 ) {
          for ( var clientNdx = 0; clientNdx < clientsExposed.length; clientNdx++ ) {
              //  Will the new allocation smother an existing allocaton
              if ( clientsExposures[clientNdx][0] > smotherLimit && clientsExposures[clientNdx][0] - clientsExposures[clientNdx][1] <= smotherLimit ) return true;
          }
          //  Will the new allocation be smothered by an existing allocation
          if ( alloc > smotherLimit && alloc - clientsExposures[0][1] <= smotherLimit ) return true;
      }
      return false;
  }

  function allocate(alloc, client, incr, offset) {
      for ( var i = offset; i < alloc + offset; i++ ) {
          var srvNdx = i * incr % servers.length;
          servers[srvNdx][1].push(client);
          clientsServers[clientsServers.length-1].push(servers[srvNdx][0]);
      }
  }

  function reallocate(alloc, client) {
      //  This does not yet check for smothering
      for ( var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++ ) {
          if ( ! servers[i][1].includes(client) ) {
              servers[i][1].push(client)
              alloc -= 1;
              if ( alloc == 0 ) break;
          }
      }
      if ( alloc > 0 ) {
          servers.sort(
              (a,b) => {
                  if ( a[1].length < b[1].length ) return -1;
                  if ( a[1].length > b[1].length ) return 1;
                  return 0;
              }
          );
          for ( var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++ ) {
              servers[i][1].push(client)
              if ( alloc == 1 ) break;
              alloc -= 1;
          }
      }   
  }

  function act() {
      if ( nextAction < shardActions.length ) {
          document.getElementById("warnings").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("action" + ( nextAction - 1 )).style.background = "none";
          document.getElementById("action" + ( nextAction )).style.background = "lime";
          var nextAct = shardActions[nextAction];
          if ( nextAct[1] == "s" ) {
              if ( nextAct[0] == "+" ) {
                  //  Add one or more servers
                  var newServers = [];
                  for ( var i = 0; i < nextAct[3]; i++ ) {
                      newServers.push([ nextServerId, [] ]);
                      nextServerId += 1;
                  }
                  servers = [ ...newServers, ...servers ];
              } else {
                  //  Remove client and their servers

                  //  Get other clients' exposures to the client's servers.
                  var clientsExposed = [];
                  var clientsExposures = [];
                  var srvNdxes = []
                  var ndx = clientsName.indexOf(nextAct[2]);
                  for ( var i = 0; i < clientsServers[ndx].length; i++ ) {
                      for ( var srvNdx = 0; srvNdx < servers.length; srvNdx++ ) {
                          if ( servers[srvNdx][0] == clientsServers[ndx][i] ) {
                              if ( ! srvNdxes.includes(srvNdx) ) srvNdxes.push(srvNdx);
                              for ( var j = 0; j < servers[srvNdx][1].length; j++ ) {
                                  if ( servers[srvNdx][1][j] != nextAct[2] ) {
                                      var clientNdx = clientsExposed.indexOf(servers[srvNdx][1][j]);
                                      if ( clientNdx == -1 ) {
                                          clientsExposed.push(servers[srvNdx][1][j]);
                                          clientsExposures.push([ 1, [ servers[srvNdx][0] ] ]);
                                      } else {
                                          clientsExposures[clientNdx][0] += 1;
                                          if ( ! clientsExposures[clientNdx][1].includes(servers[srvNdx][0]) ) clientsExposures[clientNdx][1].push(servers[srvNdx][0])
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }

                  //  Remove client's servers
                  srvNdxes.sort().reverse();
                  for ( var i = 0; i < srvNdxes.length; i++ ) {
                      servers.splice(srvNdxes[i], 1);
                  }
                  //  Remove servers from exposed clients
                  for ( var i = 0; i < clientsExposed.length; i++ ){
                      var clientServers = clientsServers[clientsName.indexOf(clientsExposed[i])];
                      for ( var j = 0; j < clientsExposures[i][1]; j++ ) {
                          clientServers.splice(clientServers.indexOf(clientsExposures[i][1][j]), 1);
                      }
                  }
                  
                  //  Remove the client
                  var clientNdx = clientsName.indexOf(nextAct[2]);
                  clientsName.splice(clientNdx, 1);
                  clientsServers.splice(clientNdx, 1);
                  clientsProcesses.splice(clientNdx, 1);

                  //  Reallocate other exposed clients
                  servers.sort(
                      (a,b) => {
                          if ( a[1].length < b[1].length ) return -1;
                          if ( a[1].length > b[1].length ) return 1;
                          return 0;
                      }
                  );
                  for ( var i = 0; i < clientsExposed.length; i++ ) {
                      reallocate(clientsExposures[i][0], clientsExposed[i]);
                      servers.sort(
                          (a,b) => {
                              if ( a[1].length < b[1].length ) return -1;
                              if ( a[1].length > b[1].length ) return 1;
                              return 0;
                          }
                      );
                  }

              }
              document.getElementById("activeservers").innerHTML = servers.length;
              displayServers();
          } else {  //  nextAct[1] == "c"
              if ( nextAct[0] == "+" ) {
                  //  Add client and client processes
                  if ( clientsName.includes( nextAct[2]) ) {
                      document.getElementById("warnings").innerHTML = "Client, " + nextAct[2] + ", already exists.";
                  } else {
                      var offset = 0
                      var incr = 1;
                      var check = smothering(nextAct[3], incr, offset);
                      while ( check && incr < servers.length ) {
                          incr += 1;
                          check = smothering(nextAct[3], incr, offset);
                      }
                      if ( incr == servers.length ) {
                          offset = 1;
                          incr = 1;
                          check = smothering(nextAct[3], incr, offset);
                          while ( check && incr < servers.length ) {
                              incr += 1;
                              check = smothering(nextAct[3], incr, offset);
                          }
                      }
                      if ( incr == servers.length ) {
                          document.getElementById("warnings").innerHTML = "Cannot spread " + nextAct[2] + ".";
                          incr = 1;
                      } else if ( incr > 1 ) {
                          document.getElementById("warnings").innerHTML = "Spreading " + nextAct[2] + ".";
                      }

                      clientsServers.push([]);
                      allocate(nextAct[3], nextAct[2], incr, offset);
                      clientsName.push(nextAct[2]);
                      clientsProcesses.push(nextAct[3]);
                  }
                  
              } else {  //  nextAct[0] == "-"
                  //  Remove client and client processes
                  var clientNdx = clientsName.indexOf(nextAct[2]);
                  for ( var i = 0; i < clientsServers[clientNdx].length; i++ ) {
                      for ( var srvNdx = 0; srvNdx < servers.length; srvNdx++ ) {
                          if ( servers[srvNdx][0] == clientsServers[clientNdx][i] ) {
                              var ndx = servers[srvNdx][1].indexOf(nextAct[2]);
                              while ( ndx > -1 ) {
                                  servers[srvNdx][1].splice(ndx, 1);
                                  ndx = servers[srvNdx][1].indexOf(nextAct[2]);
                              }
                              break;
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  clientsName.splice(clientNdx, 1);
                  clientsServers.splice(clientNdx, 1);
                  clientsProcesses.splice(clientNdx, 1);
              }
              servers.sort(
                  (a,b) => {
                      if ( a[1].length < b[1].length ) return -1;
                      if ( a[1].length > b[1].length ) return 1;
                      return 0;
                  }
              );
              document.getElementById("minimumclients").innerHTML = servers[0][1].length;
              document.getElementById("maximumclients").innerHTML = servers[servers.length-1][1].length;
              displayServers();
          }
          nextAction += 1;
      }
  }

  function onload() {
      var actions = '<tr id="action-1"><th>Action</th><th>Object</th><th>Client Name</th><th>Number</th></tr>';
      for ( var i = 0; i < shardActions.length; i++ ) {
          var action = '';
          if ( shardActions[i][0] == "+" ) {
              action += '<td>Add</td>';
          } else {  //  shardActions[i][0] == "-"
              action += '<td>Remove</td>';
          }
          if ( shardActions[i][1] == "s" ) {
              action += '<td>Server/s</td>' + '<td style="background: ' + shardActions[i][2] + ';">' + shardActions[i][2] + '</td>';
          } else {  //  shardActions[i][1] == "c"
              action += '<td>Client</td>' + '<td style="background: ' + shardActions[i][2] + ';">' + shardActions[i][2] + '</td>';
          }
          action += '<td>' + shardActions[i][3] + '</td>';
          actions += '<tr id="action' + i + '">' + action + '</tr>';
      }
      document.getElementById("actions").innerHTML = actions;
      document.getElementById("activeservers").innerHTML = 0;
      document.getElementById("minimumclients").innerHTML = 0;
      document.getElementById("maximumclients").innerHTML = 0;
      displayServers();
  }
  ```

  ```css
  table {
      display: inline-table;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin: 15px;
  }

  body > div {
      background: wheat;
  }

  div > div {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
      background: white;
      min-width: 200px;
  }

  #stats {
      background: white;
  }

  #actions {
      text-align: center;
  }

  #servers th,
  #servers td,
  #stats th,
  #stats td,
  #actions th,
  #actions td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 3px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <body onload="onload()">
  <div>
  <div onclick="act()">Click here to step through actions.</div>
  <table id="stats">
  <tr><td>Servers</td><td id="activeservers"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Minimum server clients</td><td id="minimumclients"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Maximum server clients</td><td id="maximumclients"></td></tr>
  </table>
  <div id="warnings"></div>
  </div>
  <table id="actions">
  </table>
  <table id="servers">
  </table>
  </body>
  ```